# Power Query - Dynamically pass a file path into File.Contents function

Tags: firewall, file-get-contents, powerquery

I have the below code which pulls txt data from a file and gets used in an Excel lookup.

```
 let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("J:\Accounting\Dallas\2020 Finance\BPC Trial Balances\BPC Upload text files\05.MAY\2020.MAY_USA_v2.txt"),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column5", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

I created a parameter table with Source Files table column, and created a parameter value for each of the 5 rows, to dynamically feed this query. The below is the attempt

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(vUSA),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column5", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

THe problem is this doesn't work, but the syntax is OK it seems as I get

> "Formula.Firewall: Query 'USA' (step 'Changed Type') references other
>   queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please
>   rebuild this data combination."

Answer (score 1):

I figured out it was my Power Query Settings  . I used the below to reconcile the issue 
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Formula-Firewall-Query-references-other-queries-so-it-may-not/td-p/18619